# links module in DotNetNuke

Tags: dotnetnuke

I want to add links module to my DotNetNuke Application but it can't be appeared in the module dropdownlist in the add module control panel. Please give me suggestion from where we can retrieve the links module.....

Answer (score 1):

It would be a good idea to use the DotNetNuke forums, I guess this is a standard DNN module?
http://www.dotnetnuke.com/tabid/795/default.aspx

Maybe you mean where can I download the latest version of the links module?
Try the download section:
http://www.dotnetnuke.com/tabid/125/default.aspx

Or maybe how to install the module?
Login as a Host go to (menu) Host>Module Definitions

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a standard DNN module.  If the links module doesn't appear as a standard module in your installation, you have an installation problem.

Go to your main installation folder.  Go to the bin directory and make sure DotNetNuke.Modules.Links.dll is there.  Go ahead and replace that with the newest version from http://www.DotNetNuke.com.

Then restart your website.

Answer (score 0):

**Legacy DNN Links - DNN 4 & Under**

Also, if this was in an older DNN 4x instance, the Links module may be in the "install folder" making it available for install in DNN but may not be actively installed. You may want to check out the HOST > Extensions page and then click on the triangle menu for "install available extensions"

there you'll see a full list of all the modules and perhaps other newer versions that are ready for install (uploaded as zip or package to the install folder of dnn).

Once they're installed, they then show in the Module Definitions page and in the control panel as active modules that can be installed on a page

**DNN Links Module Today (DNN 7+)**

For anyone looking for the newest versions of this very helpful module, know that it is no longer part of the "core" that is installed with every dnn instance, instead you have to download and install it like any other module.

you can find it on their CodePlex location (which I find easy to download from) 
but it has also been moved to a GitHub location as of summer 2015. this is the location that will continue to receive updates

github > DNNCommunity/DNN.Links